# Particles not view in preview render or render view

Tags: particles, camera, image

With the mesh selected i have a png image. I want my image facing the camera view. Im not animating. Just want my image to focus camera. I tried the particles setting. In the sold view i can see my png image.

**(with the object option its visible. 
with the billboard options its invisible)**

[image]

When i tried to render or preview render i cannnot see my png image. Any suggestion or help. Thanks

[image]

Comment: Try to bake (cache) them.

Comment: @brockmann i clear cache. did not work

Comment: @brockmann with the object option its visible. with the billboard options its invisible

Comment: are they visible when you look through the main camera?

Comment: @FrederikSteinmetz Yes it is visible from main camera. here is the screenshot https://imgur.com/gallery/WBraKVR

Comment: Billboards always face the camera, so if you are not looking through it, there's a chance they disappear, because their thickness is 0.